# Link on Facebook with custom prefix/protocol (like myapp://blahblah)

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, custom-url

I added to my iOS application option to detect and response to custom URL schemes to launch application ( http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html ).

Link is working perfectly on different sites (using href), but I'm having problem with Facebook. If I'm trying to post link (using Graph API) which looks like:

```
myapp://blabla
```

Facebook return error:

> The url you supplied is invalid

And for feed with link return

> link URL is not properly formatted.

I can't just post url as a message because it's not being detected as a URL and appear like text only.

Is there any way to post to Facebook wall with custom links?

**Edit:**
I have an idea, but I don't know if it gonna work. Putting 
*myapp://blabla* directly into address field in mobile browser is launching application so probably accessing an webpage (like http://www.mywebpage/myapp) with only redirection to 
*myapp://blabla* gonna work too, but is Facebook gonna accept that link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your suggestion in the edit is the correct method, and should work. However applications like spotify seem to use an intersticial page which fires the "app link" with javascript, the advantage to this approach is that you can use that page to "sell" the app to users who don't have it and also provide lovely open graph tags for people who want to share it.

Comment: It is working well. Tested just after I posted my edition, but I couldn't answer my question that fast:P

I had to add small delay (1 second) before redirection because when redirection starts before 'animation' of opening browsers' new tap end cause weird bug (tested only on Safari) with white block hiding whole content of webpages and after all caused Safari crash. With delay no bugs occurred.

Thanks

Comment: You are both very talented programmers, this has to be one of the most underrated questions on SO I've ever seen. Thank you!